# How to make vertical spacings evenly distributed in aligned equations?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, align, amsmath, vertical-spacing

For aesthetical reasons, I often have to hack my **aligned** equations to make them vertically evenly distributed, by adding many `\vphantom` objects, or by using `\\[1ex]`, `\\[1em]`.  See this MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

%\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1em}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\belowdisplayskip}
\setlength{\jot}{3ex}

\begin{align}
    \frac{d }{d \sigma} \, A &= \frac{d }{d \sigma} \, B \\
    &= x + y + z \\
    &= c + d + p - q = 0 \\
    &= \frac{3 a^2}{4 b^3} \,\int_a^b f(x) \, dx.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

The vertical spacing is variable, and appears to be relatively nice, in this simple example.  But I find it frequently odd, or ugly in many other cases.  I would like to make it uniform, without hacking or adding `\vphantom` commands.

Is there a way, for a given align environment, to add a simple command to make all the local equations (i.e. in *that* environment) evenly seperated, using maybe the largest vertical spacing?